# Linux install in flash card

Tags: linux, installation, card-reader, memory-card

1. I can't understand why Linux on flash card needs an install, does it simply copy certain file to certain location in flash card?

   I mean, plan it in a response file, then one program read the plan in response file and write certain format to flash card.
2. Does the filesystem bind tightly to the Linux kernel? Is it possible let each kernel, user, app have its own root? Rather than mount everything under one single "root"?

Comment: this barely makes sense as is.

Comment: I believe 1 is asking why Linux on flash drives requires an install. 2 I don't get either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On PCs, the Flash card needs the MBR and bootsectors written. This is a limit of the BIOS.
2. The is called `chroot`, which can be useful but also problematic, and deserves its own question.

Comment: does the linux on flash card have chroot yet?

Comment: could users be chrooted? the guest don't share the some structure of folders of admin.

Comment: @Johnny - How could you chroot a user? Did you even read the manpage for chroot?

Comment: sorry,i haven't.